# Mocking Vuex getters for unit tests yields unexpected result

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vuex

I'm writing unit tests for VueJS components and am using [this article](https://medium.com/@lachlanmiller_52885/mocking-vuex-in-vue-unit-tests-b6eda1c4d301) as a reference for testing components that have the Vuex store as a dependency. Here are the relevant parts of the component in question:

```
<!-- COMPONENT -->

<template>
    <div>
      {{ resources.main.copyIco }} {{ resources.main.rights }} {{ resources.main.read }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
      computed: {
          ...mapGetters({
              resources: 'resources'
          })
      },
      methods: {
          ...mapActions({
              dispatchAction: 'dispatchAction'
          })
      }
   }
</script>
```

Here is what my test suite for the component looks like:

```
/* Test suite for component */

import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import AppFooter from '@/components/AppFooter/AppFooter'
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

describe('AppFooter component', () => {   

    it('instantiates the component correctly', () => {
        const localVue = createLocalVue()
        localVue.use(Vuex)
        /* define mock getters */
        const getters = {
            resources: () => 'resources'
        }
        const store = new Vuex.Store({ getters })
        const wrapper = shallowMount(AppFooter, {
            store,
            localVue
        })

        console.log('test suite does not reach this point due to error')
    })
})
```

What's interesting about this is that when I run the Jest test suite, the error reads as follows:

[image]

To me, this seems strange because (taken into context with the component template), it looks like the `resources.main` property is well-defined but that `resources.main.copyIco` is not. Otherwise, if `resources.main` was not well-defined, that would be the error instead of what's seen in the picture.

In a nutshell, why is this error occurring based on how both the component and suite are set up? Do I need to redefine the mapGetters within the component?

Answer (score 2):

In your example your getter is just returning a string named `resources` and that has no `main` property. This has nothing to do with Vue.

`resources.main` is `undefined`. And now your program tries to get the `copyIco` property of `undefined`. The error is message is right. It cannot read the `copyIco` of `undefined`.

One way to mock this better would be something along those lines.

```
const getters = {
    resources: () => ({ main: { copyIco: 'something', rights: 'rights'}})
}
```